# Selenium IDE to create fb group redactor (or div text input field)

Tags: selenium, css-selectors, selenium-ide

I have some HTML with a (facebook Description text for an event) where I need to enter text, however I cannot find where or how I can add the text, which is a div, span or other. I think this is a redactor (but I'm no expert!)

```
<th class="_3sts">
<!-- react-text: 77 -->Description
<!-- /react-text -->
</th>
<td class="_480u">
<div class="_mh-">
<div class="_56ji _5yk1">
  <div tabindex="-2" class="_5yk2">
    <div class="_5rp7">
      <div class="_1p1t _1p1u">
        <div class="_1p1v">Tell people more about the event</div>
      </div>
      <div class="_5rpb">
        <div style="outline: medium none; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; background-color: transparent;" title="Tell people more about the event" spellcheck="false" role="combobox" class="_5rpu" aria-owns="js_g" aria-haspopup="false"
        aria-expanded="false" aria-autocomplete="list" contenteditable="true">
          <div data-contents="true">
            <div data-offset-key="9c3am-0-0" data-editor="dvke2" data-block="true" class="">
              <div class="_1mf _1mj" data-offset-key="9c3am-0-0"><span data-offset-key="9c3am-0-0"><br data-text="true"></span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</td>
```

I have tried these in Selenium IDE:

```
<tr>
<td>type</td>
<td>//div[@title='Tell people more about the event']</td>
<td>testing</td>
</tr>
```

and

```
<tr>
<td>type</td>
<td>//th[text()=&quot;Description&quot;]/../td/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/span/</td>
<td>test</td>
</tr>
```

and (to apply a redactor solution)

```
<tr>
<td>runScript</td>
<td>$(._5rpu).html('text');</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

But while I can easily identify the area (one of the many divs) that seem to reflect the space where the text should go I can't manipulate it. Any help appreciated! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That field is not a trivial case.

First of all it's not an input. That's why "type" command will not work even if you will find element properly.

Secondly the div is in dynamic change when you are entering text that's why you cant use sendKeys for long text because this command is sending symbols one by one to the element that was located once. So after the first successful symbol sending, DOM of the element will be changed and it will become impossible to finish sending other keys.

**But you can send one symbol** using sendKeys like that:

```
sendKeys | //div[@class='_5rpu'] | Y
```

Finally because of unknown reason you can't send symbols with series of sendKeys commands like:

```
sendKeys | //div[@class='_5rpu'] | Y
sendKeys | //div[@class='_5rpu'] | O
```

That will throw an exception

```
[error] Unexpected Exception: Error: Cannot set the selection end.
```

The only way I've found is to use an ancient and deprecated typeKeys. After typeKeys command you also need a click a whole div which is containing field because orthodox typeKeys is working incorrect with that strange field too.

Also you need to be fully sure that all the animations was showed before you will start. That's why I recommend a small pause before you will try to type to the field.

**So here is the final and working code:**

```
pause    | 2
typeKeys | //div[@class='_5rpu'] | myDescription
click    | //div[@class='_56ji _5yk1']
```